# Replace lines matching a pattern with lines from another file in order

Tags: text-processing, files, sed, awk, perl

I want to replace the lines matching a pattern from one file from the lines in order from another file, for example, given:

**file1.txt**:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
!! 1234
!! 4567
ccccc
ddddd
!! 1111
```

we like to replace the lines starting with !! with the lines of this file:

**file2.txt**:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

so the result should be:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
first line
second line
ccccc
ddddd
third line
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy can be done with **awk**

```
awk '
    /^!!/{                    #for line stared with `!!`
        getline <"file2.txt"  #read 1 line from outer file into $0 
    }
    1                         #alias for `print $0`
    ' file1.txt
```

Other version

```
awk '
    NR == FNR{         #for lines in first file
        S[NR] = $0     #put line in array `S` with row number as index 
        next           #starts script from the beginning
    }
    /^!!/{             #for line stared with `!!`
        $0=S[++count]  #replace line by corresponded array element
    }
    1                  #alias for `print $0`
    ' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Simpler than my awk attempt :)

Comment: Costas, +1 but consider adding some explanation for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed`, similar to `awk+getline`

```
$ sed -e '/^!!/{R file2.txt' -e 'd}' file1.txt
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
first line
second line
ccccc
ddddd
third line
```

- `R` would give a line one at a time
- order is important, first `R` and then `d`

With `perl`

```
$ < file2.txt perl -pe '$_ = <STDIN> if /^!!/' file1.txt
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
first line
second line
ccccc
ddddd
third line
```

- pass the file with replacing lines as standard input, so that we can read it using `<STDIN>` filehandle
- if matching line is found, replace `$_` with a line from standard input